# Will space be allocated for unused variables and functions in gnu compiler while making bin file

Tags: c

Will space be allocated for unused variables 
and functions in gnu compiler,
while making the bin file.

Comment: Can you explain your situation why this problem become a concern of you? Do you want to make the resultant bin file more compact or anything?

Comment: We have couple of legacy code files. Entire parts of this code were used before for compilation. So now the bin file not getting generated due to overflow(greater than 256kb).But with optimisation level O0, commenting the unused code parts, we dont find much variation on bin size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.
For example on the optimization level.

If you want to be sure, that something shows up in your binary, use `__attribute__((used))`.

> This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be
>   emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not
>   referenced. This is useful, for example, when the function is
>   referenced only in inline assembly. When applied to a member function
>   of a C++ class template, the attribute also means that the function is
>   instantiated if the class itself is instantiated.

[src](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). Very useful if you have dynamic linked libraries associated with you binary that rely on certain symbols existence.

If you want to be sure that something unused does not appear in your binary, compile it with debug symbols and check that it does not show up.
To make sure that an unused local variable is optimized away, I know not better way than stepping through the disassembled compiled binary.

Comment: That should apply only to static functions -- the compiler cannot optimise out external functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

GCC will put global variables and all external functions into the object code, used or otherwise. However, uninitialised data usually takes no space.

Automatic variables are allocated at runtime, so these aren't stored in the binary.

You may be able to ask the linker to remove code, for example, with GNU ld:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -Wl,--gc-sections
```

This may remove unused variables and functions from the final code.